# How to display values in a database show.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new using ruby on rails, my problem is mainly that I can not display the table of students in my show.html.erb file, anyone can guide me how I can add multiple columns with the titles of the data I need, and that the bottom of the table content is displayed?

example:

name   surname   enrollment    gender
louis  brand     1658798sr5t   male

Comment: [Read the docs.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller **app/controllers/students_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @students = Student.all
end
```

And in your view **app/views/students/show.html.erb**:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <%= @students.each do |student| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= student.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I would you suggest to read this post:

http://ruby.about.com/od/rails4/ss/Quick-Rails-4-Blog-Tutorial.htm

Maybe:

https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux

http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-rails-3-part-1/

Enjoy!

Comment: According to JayX, you will need to fill your @students instance variable in your the show method of your students_controller.rb

Answer (score 4):

in your show.html.erb page

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>surname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <% @students.each do |s| %>
      <td><%= s.name %></td>
      <td><%= s.surname %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think you get the idea

and get @students from your show method under students controller

```
  def show
    @students = Student.all
  end
```

I hope that helps